# Printing elements from XPath results in more than the elements

Tags: javascript, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs, selectors-api

All I want to do is return a string from an xpath I determined but I'm having trouble using the `getElementsByXPath` function in CasperJS.

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: false,
logLevel: 'debug'
});
casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36");
casper.start();
casper.thenOpen('http://www.uky.edu', function(){
    content = casper.evaluate(function () {
       return __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//div[@id=\'container\']/section[@id=\'content\']/aside[@class=\'socialTab clearfix\']/div[@id=\'usual2\']/div[@id=\'tabs1\']/figure[@class=\'youTube\']/h4/a');
   });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(content)); 
    this.echo('completed').exit();
});
```

Doesn't stop returning data. And it is definitely not returning that particular string I'm looking for, it seems like it's returning the data for the entire webpage instead.

I ended up trying this with a practically blank webpage with just one div and got the same issue
I used //div for the xpath and received the following

```
[{"align":"","attributes":{"length":0},"baseURI":"http://download2012.ad.uky.edu/caspertest.php","childElementCount":0,"childNodes":{"0":null,"length":1},"child
ren":{"length":0},"classList":{"length":0},"className":"","clientHeight":20,"cli
entLeft":0,"clientTop":0,"clientWidth":384,"contentEditable":"inherit","dataset"
:{},"dir":"","draggable":false,"firstChild":null,"firstElementChild":"","hidden"
:false,"id":"","innerHTML":"Test2","innerText":"Test2","isContentEditable":false
,"lang":"","lastChild":{"attributes":"","baseURI":"http://download2012.ad.uky.ed
u/caspertest.php","childNodes":{"length":0},"data":"Test2","firstChild":"","last
Child":"","length":5,"localName":"","namespaceURI":"","nextSibling":"","nodeName
":"#text","nodeType":3,"nodeValue":"Test2","ownerDocument":null,"parentElement":
null,"parentNode":null,"prefix":"","previousSibling":"","textContent":"Test2","w
holeText":"Test2"},"lastElementChild":"","localName":"div","namespaceURI":"http:
//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","nextElementSibling":"","nextSibling":null,"nodeName":"
DIV","nodeType":1,"nodeValue":"","offsetHeight":20,"offsetLeft":8,"offsetParent"
:{"aLink":"","attributes":{"length":0},"background":"","baseURI":"http://downloa
d2012.ad.uky.edu/caspertest.php","bgColor":"","childElementCount":1,"childNodes"
:{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"length":3},"children":{"0":null,"length":1},"class
List":{"length":0},"className":"","clientHeight":300,"clientLeft":0,"clientTop":
0,"clientWidth":400,"contentEditable":"inherit","dataset":{},"dir":"","draggable
":false,"firstChild":{"attributes":"","baseURI":"http://download2012.ad.uky.edu/
caspertest.php","childNodes":{"length":0},"data":"Test\n","firstChild":"","lastC
hild":"","length":5,"localName":"","namespaceURI":"","nextSibling":null,"nodeNam
e":
```

And so on.

Comment: On an unrelated note: The XPath expression is quite rigid. Why not use `//div[@id='tabs1']/figure[@class='youTube']/h4/a`?

Comment: I added a more complete example.I also changed it so it is less rigid. There was no reason for it to be so rigid. I'm just still learning how XPaths work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return DOM elements from page context in CasperJS. If `document.querySelectorAll` is used instead of `__utils__.getElementsByXPath` (with adjusted CSS selector), the result will be an array of `undefined` values. This is not the case for `__utils__.getElementsByXPath`. Snapshots of DOM elements are returned which are actually partially serializable. The problem is that they contain circular references to the document and will grow continuously.

From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!**

You need to do everything that you want to do in the page context. For example the element as a string:

```
content = casper.evaluate(function () {
   return __utils__.getElementByXPath(someSelector).outerHTML;
});
```

Comment: It's returning null for some reason

Comment: Note the lack of `s` in `getElementByXPath`. If you use `getElementsByXPath` you have to map the elements or iterate over them.